# why the generated function throws out the not defined error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate a JS script using JS sounds tricky. But the function inside the generated script comes to form and I try to call, it says undefined I'm giving a minimalistic example of my code. I don't know why it's happening maybe function defining on appending or changing the inner html does not work. If you can figure it out that how I can solve this problem, please tell me it'll help out a lot. Thanks! here is the example code.

```html
   <body>
<script>
    
    let b = '<script>function amb(){console.log("hello")}' + '<' + '/' + 'script>'

    document.body.innerHTML = b
</script>
<div id="a">
    <button onclick="amb()"> amb</button>
   
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using innerHTML to add a script will not work, you need to create a script element and append it to the body

Comment: Because adding a tag doesn't evaluate the script.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? Why do you need to "generate a JS script using JS"?

Comment: @AKX my goal is to minimalize my code that why using js.

Comment: @Lk77 i tried to use script tag but in head but it also did'nt work

Comment: @AwaisMehnga What do you mean with "my goal is to minimalize my code"?

Comment: From your other comment: "I'm making a website which is used to generate tables it requires a form but I'm too lazy to write hundreds lines of html" – so generate those tables in a loop in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

That is probably because it is not loaded if you just add it afterwards. Nevertheless generating code with code should be avoided! If anywhere input data is used it is that vulnerability. Also it is bad code and hard to understand.

You should overthink your concept and maybe try to explain what you want to achieve and search for in the internet. Or maybe we can here give you a suggestion.

With the suggestion from @Lk77
A solution I would **NOT** recommend! could look like:

```html
<div>
    <button> amb</button>   
</div>
```

```js
let s = document.createElement('script');
s.text = 'function amb(){ console.log("hello"); }'
document.body.appendChild(s);

document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', amb);
```

regarding your answer in the comments

> I'm making a website which is used to generate tables it requires a form but I'm too lazy to write hundreds lines of html so i used js but someone has told me that the code generated afterwards is not loaded. I don't know how can i load the generated code

try to think simple... instead of generating code to generate you sth. use js to generate html that's the purpose of js. 100% sure you don't need to code code that generates code. You can create a website that is 99% powered by javascript that kind is called webapp. https://angular.io/start is one of many frameworks to achieve that. And none of them generates code by code.

Comment: yes, but is there any way to load the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't use innerHTML, you will need to append to the body :

```
var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
s.text = 'alert("test")'
document.body.appendChild( s );
```

but the real question is why you want to do that

Comment: I'm making a website which is used to generate tables it requires a form but I'm too lazy to write hundreds lines of html so i used js but someone has told me that the code generated afterwards is not loaded. I don't know how can i load the generated code

Comment: Well you can load it using createElement and append it to the body, but i'm sure you can have a static js file that does the same thing